# Disable Gutenberg only for page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I would like to disable Gutenberg only for page but not for the post

```
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);
add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check below code snippet.

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2 );
function prefix_disable_gutenberg( $current_status, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'page' === $post_type ) return false;
    return $current_status;
}
```